# How to convert string to int in processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I am trying to make a hands free mouse using Arduino IDE and Processing IDE. I don't have a problem with serializing the code and converting to string, but when I try and convert the serial string into int the int goes to 0. I have tried to trim it and used `integer.parseInt` but it still gives me the error:

```
NumberFormatException : For input String:"".
```

Here is my code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Robot;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
Robot robot;
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
boolean valtrue;
int xy = 0;
int x=0;

void setup()
{
    String portName = Serial.list()[3]; 
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
    myPort.bufferUntil('.');
    try { 
        robot = new Robot();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
void draw() {
    //reading serial port until \n
    String sensorValue = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (sensorValue != null) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(sensorValue.trim());
        println(value);
    }
}
```

If anyone is able to help, please answer.

Answer (score 1):

Processing has an `int()` function that you can use instead of `Integer.parseInt()`. Behind the scenes the `int()` function is calling the `Integer.parseInt()` function, but it's shorter. Up to you.

But your error says it all: you're passing an empty `String` value `""` into the `parseInt()` function. An empty `String` value can't be turned into a number, so you get the exception.

You're going to have to track down why your `String` value is empty, but that's what's causing this particular error. I will point out that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second, and you're trying to read from your port every single time, so maybe you're reading faster than you're writing?